# Implementing infinite scrolling in reactjs using json data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, react-hooks, frontend

```
function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(10);
  // const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const count = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => getTenDataFirst(json));
  }, []);

  function getTenDataFirst(data) {
    data.splice(page)
    setResponse(data)
  }

  const handelInfiniteScroll = async () => {
    console.log("scrollHeight" + count.current.scrollHeight);
    console.log("innerHeight" + count.current.innerHeight);
    console.log("scrollTop" + count.current.scrollTop);
  };

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='box' ref={count} onScroll={() => handelInfiniteScroll()}>
        {
          response?.length > 0 && response?.map((data) => {
            return (
              <div key={data['id']}>{data['name']}</div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Implementing infinite scrolling in reactjs using json data but onscroll getting innerHeight undefined. Is there any other way to implement infinite scrolling in reactjs without using third party library or JavaScript syntax**

Comment: That's because innerHight only exist on the window object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IntersectionObserver Api to achieve this.

A simple hook would look something like this:

```
const useOnScreen = (ref) => {
  const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting] = useState(false);

  const observer = useMemo(
    () =>
      new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) =>
        setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting)
      ),
    [ref]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    observer.observe(ref?.current);
    return () => observer.disconnect();
  }, []);

  return isIntersecting;
};

// usage of hook
const bottomRef = useRef(null);
const isVisible = useOnScreen(bottomRef);
    
return (
  <div>
    // list of items here
    <div ref={bottomRef}/>
  </div>
)
```